# How can I bold first HTML rows in the crontab script

Tags: html, sql, cron

Please help me to get the sql output of crontab scripts of first row to be bold.

Comment: please tag you questions to SQL so that experts will help you

Comment: Hello Team, Please help me to get the sql output of crontab scripts of first row to be bold.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
# Oracle Variables
#export TIME_STAMP=`date +"%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S"`
#dt=$(date --date yesterday "+%a %d/%m/%Y")
year=$(date +'%Y')
#dt=$(date --date yesterday "+%a %d/%m/%Y")
dt=$(date --date today "+%a %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

Comment: yestday=$(date --date yesterday "+%d/%m/%Y")
yestweek=$(date --date="1 week ago" +%d/%m/%Y)
month=$(date -d "last month" +"%b_%Y")
export ORACLE_HOME=/c01
export ORACLE_SID=test
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export ORACLE_TERM=xterm
export ORACLE_OWNER=orauser
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/classes12.zip
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$ORACLE_HOME/lib32
export LDPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$ORACLE_HOME/lib32
export LOGFILE=/c01/Log/limit_output.log

Comment: sqlplus -S prod/prod@tnsprod  << EOF
set echo off numf 999G999G999G999 lin 32000 trims on pages 50000 head on feed off markup html off
spool /c01/scripts/Output/Limit_output.html
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON PREFORMAT OFF ENTMAP ON -
HEAD "<TITLE>BILL Report</TITLE> -
<STYLE type='text/css'> -
table { background: #eee; font-size: 70%; width:50%; } -
       th { bgcolor= #fff; } -
       td { padding: 0px; } -
</STYLE>" -

Comment: body 'text=black bgcolor=fffffff align=left' -
 table 'align=center width=70% border=3 bordercolor=black bgcolor=grey'
#set markup html on entmap off table 'align="center" width="90%" border="1" bordercolor="black" bgcolor="white"'
prompt <h3>Limit output Notification</h3>
set heading off;
set feedback 0;
set verify off;
set auto off;
set echo off;
var a REFCURSOR;
set heading off;
set feedback 0;
set verify off;
set auto off;
set echo off;
var a REFCURSOR;
call app.LIMIT_CHECK(:a);
print a;

Comment: prompt <i></i>
prompt <i></i>
prompt <i>Kind Regards,</i>
prompt <i>IT DEPARTMENT</i>
prompt <i>IT SERVICES</i>
spool off;
!echo "Spool file generated...."
clear buffer;
exit;
EOF
b=$(cat /c01/scripts/Output/Limit_output.html |wc -l)
if [ "$b" -gt 45 ]
then
echo "Limit Output Notification"
mutt -e "my_hdr  Content-Type: text/html" -e 'set realname=Notification'  -e 'set from=notification@testservices.org' prod@testservices.org -s "Limit Notification" < /c01/scripts/Output/Limit_output.html
fi
#END OF THE SCRIPT

Comment: Hello Ram sir, please help me, i have pasted my crontab script to above, please update me to get solution.

Comment: Please can you add all those comments in your question and read the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)